# Diamond issue with virtual function implementation

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

In case of diamond problem in c++,if the Base and the medium level classes have implemented a virtual function. How to remove the given error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
   virtual void display()
   {
       cout<<"In Base"<<endl;
   }
};

class Der1:virtual public Base
{
public:

    void display()
  {
    cout<<"In Der1"<<endl;
  }
};

class Der2:virtual public Base
{
    public:
    void display()
    {
       cout<<"In Der2"<<endl;
    }
};

class Mix: public Der1, public Der2
{
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    Mix m_mix;
    m_mix.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting below error :-

main.cpp:50: error: request for member 'display' is ambiguous
     m_mix.display();

How can we access display() of Der1 and Der2 using object of Mix class?

Comment: *what* "virtual" function ?

Comment: `Mix` inherits `display` from two different classes. There's no way to determine which one should be called. Add `using Der1::display;`, `using Der2::display;`, or override the `display` function in `Mix`.

Comment: I'm not sure the edit of making `display()` virtual is valid. The compile error clearly suggests it's not.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve ambiguity, one could specify the function explicitly, e.g.:

```
m_mix.Der1::display();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no `virtual` functions in your code. But it wouldn't matter if there were. (update: come to think of it, if `display()` *were* virtual then `Mix` as a class wouldn't compile because which function do you put in the vtable? You'd get an error without even calling `display()`).

When you call `Mix::display()`, there are two choices: `Der1::display()` and `Der2::display()`. It is impossible for the compiler to distinguish between them, so rather than trying to guess at what you want, it tells you that it cannot. So you just have to be explicit:

```
m_mix.Der1::display();
```

or

```
static_cast<Der1&>(m_mix).display();
```

or write a `Mix::display()` function that does whatever it is you want to do.

Comment: I have tried m_mix.Der1::display() and I am getting the following error: no unique final overrider for 'virtual void Base::display()' in 'Mix' if I do not override display() in Mix class.So Is it necessary to do the same?

Comment: @learner that's a different problem than the one you originally posted. There, you need a unique override for `display()` and you have two. So you'll need to provide a `Mix::display()` override for it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

Call like this:-

```
m_mix.Der1::display ();
```

OR

```
m_mix.Der2::display ();
```

Comment: I am getting the following  error: no unique final overrider for 'virtual void Base::display()' in 'Mix'
if I do not override display() in Mix class.So Is it necessary to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

I spot another error in your code: class Mix Error: override of virtual function "Base::display" is ambiguous. This is because in your base class **void display() is virtual**.

```
class Base
{
    public:
   virtual void display()
   {
       cout<<"In Base"<<endl;
   }
};
```

Therefore, in the class Mix there should be an implementation of the void display().

```
class Mix: public Der1, public Der2
{
   // need to implement void display()
};
```